# When using argparse in Python 2.7, how can I pass more than 'args' into my default function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

I'm trying to pass in some arguments to the default function of my parser, which doesn't come straight from an argument in the command line. The argument the user provides on the cli is meant to act for a lookup for the real value needed, as it real value isn't user freindly to repeatedly type in.

With argparse you can perform something like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
def test_function(args):
    print args

Parser.set_defaults(func=test_function)
args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)
```

test_function will successfully print out the args here. Notice how

```
(func=test_function)
```

doesn't pass in any parameters, it seems to just pass in args, Adding brackets here prevents passing in args, since it doesn't get pushed automatically if you do, and typing it in won't work as args hasn't been defined yet as far as Python is concerned.

I've tried also doing

```
Parser.set_defaults(func=test_function, realValue=lookup_function)
```

However realValue seems to evaluate at a reference to the function itself, rather than what the function returns (I don't think the function is even executed, so I'm not sure if this even would pass args into the lookup_function).

I *could* probably call the lookup function from the test_function, however I want to avoid this as in my program these two functions are in seperate modules, and it seems a bit... messy to import them into each other rather than simply importing them both into my main.py file.

Is anyone aware of any way to do what I'm trying to do? Will I need to suck it up and import cross submodule?

**EDIT**
To try and be a bit more clear I want to pass args **and** another dynamic value into test_function, through argparse's functionality of;

```
    Parser.set_defaults(func=test_function)
```

the dynamic value is found by using one of the values of args. I wish to know a way to pass into test_function, or args itself, a new value which is returned by another function.

Comment: can you make this more clear? and more code?

Comment: im not sure what your trying to do... but whatever it is this does not seem like the right way to do it ...

Comment: @TylerCowan Which part do you not understand? I'm new to asking questions here, and I don't do a lot of programming with other people, so I'm not sure what else to provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the part where you only pass `args` to `args.func`:

```
args.func(args)
#         ^^^^ this bit!
```

If you want to pass other things to `args.func`, just pass them!

```
args.func(whatever, the, heck, you, want)
```

If you want `args.func` to receive `3`, `"fish"`, and `"sweaters"` as arguments, you can do that:

```
args.func(3, "fish", "sweaters")
```

`args.func` will immediately choke on those arguments, of course, since you wrote it to only expect the namespace object as an argument. You can define it to take different arguments:

```
def test_function(number, animal, garments):
    print("I stuffed", number, garments, "into a big rubber", animal, "as an art project.")
```

Comment: Whilst my own way works better for me, this answer most accurately answers the question I believe, so I've chosen it as the choosen answer. Thank you @user2357112

Answer (score 1):

I ended up finding the way myself, I was over looking something pretty simple.
For some reason I didn't join these two together in my head.

```
   Parser.set_defaults(func=test_function)
args.func(args)
```

I figured this was inbuilt functionality in the argparse module, but it's a lot more simple than that it seems. I found a way to achieve adding the new value to args by following the correct syntax (who would've thought)

so this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
def test_function(args):
    print args

Parser.set_defaults(func=test_function, realValue=lookup_function)
args = parser.parse_args()
args.func(args)
```

becomes this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
def test_function(args):
    print args

Parser.set_defaults(realValue=lookup_function)
Parser.set_defaults(func=test_function)
args = parser.parse_args()
args.realValue(args)
args.func(args)
```

Sorry for the dumb question I guess, hopefully this helps someone who makes a similar mistake in the future

Comment: It's a good idea to `print args` during development so you have a clear(er) idea of what that is.  It will contain attributes created by the arguments as well as the `set_defaults`.  Anything that you choose to do with those attributes after parsing is outside of `argparse` (regular Python code).

Comment: A key thing to remember is a function is a object, and can be assigned to any variable or even stored in a list. `foo=test_function`; `foo(arg1, arg2, ...)`.  All `set_defaults` is doing is storing a pointer to that function object in the `args` namespace.  Your own code can do anything it wants with that object.